Calling a hook inside a useMemo workaround
Currently I am mapping through a list in my react component:
const items = useMemo(() => {
  return items.map(item => {
    const element = useSearchResult(item)
  })
  ...
}, [dependencies])

I am aware that calling a hook inside a useMemo is bad practice and should not be done. However, how can I solve this issue?
I thought of doing this:
const element = (item) => useSearchResult(item)

const items = useMemo(() => {
  return items.map(item => {
    element(item)
  })
  ...
}, [dependencies])

I don't think this solves the issue of not calling a hook inside a useMemo.
useSearchResult will return a JSX element which is based on the item prop it receives.
const useSearchResult = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {item.name}
      {item.id}
    </div>
  )
}


What does useSearchResult do?

can you include the code for useSearchResult?

@user27344519 we need to see the code for useSearchResult. The answer to your question is probably to rewrite useSearchResult so that it can be called exactly once on each render, and we can't tell you how to do that if we can't see the code.

It's a very basic component, just takes in the item prop and returns a div containing the information about the item.

const useSearchResult = ({item}) => {
 return (
   <div>
     {item.name}
     {item.id}
    </div>
 )
}

Since this code does not call any hooks (eg, useState, useEffect), it is not a custom hook. It does not need to follow the rules of hooks, meaning you can safely call it as many times as you like, and you can change the number of times on each render. The only thing you should do is change the name of it so no one (neither humans, nor automated tools like eslint) mistakenly thinks it needs to follow the rules of hooks.

If the name does not change the React hooks linting rules will still falsely flag it as an invalid React hook call, assuming the OP is using the linter rules.

useSearchResult isn't actually a React hook, it appears to be a regular React component, e.g. a function that returns JSX. You should rename to SearchResult and render it as JSX directly.
Example:
const SearchResult = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {item.name}
      {item.id}
    </div>
  );
};

return (
  ...
  {items.map(item => <SearchResult key={item.id} item={item} />)}
  ...
);

React will handle rerendering when the items "dependency" updates. If there is an issue with rerendering too often, then memoize the items array value.
const memoizedItems = useMemo(() => {
  // compute and return stable items array
}, [/* dependencies */]);

...

return (
  ...
  {memoizedItems.map(item => <SearchResult key={item.id} item={item} />)}
  ...
);

